# Scala: implicit class using a superclass generic

Tags: scala, generics, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have this code:

```scala
trait Entity[I] {
  def id:I
}

trait VersionableEntity[I] extends Entity[I] {
  def version:Long
}

case class TestEntity( id:Long, version:Long ) extends VersionableEntity[Long]
```

Inside my package object:

```scala
implicit class KGroupedVersionableEntityStreamOps[I, K, V[U] <: VersionableEntity[U]]( groupedStream:KGroupedStream[K, V[I]] ) {

  def aggregateByVersionToSet( implicit materialized:Materialized[K, Map[I, V[I]], ByteArrayKeyValueStore] ):KTable[K, Set[V[I]]] =
    groupedStream.aggregate( Map.empty[I, V[I]] )( ( _, value:V[I], map:Map[I, V[I]] ) =>
      if( map.get( value.id ).exists( _.version > value.version ) ) map
      else map + ( value.id -> value )
    )
    .mapValues( _.values.toSet )
}
```

And a test case:

```scala
val stream:KGroupedStream[String, TestEntity] = null
val table:KTable[String, Set[TestEntity]] = stream.aggregateByVersionToSet
```

And I get this error while compiling:

```scala
value aggregateByVersionToSet is not a member of org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.kstream.KGroupedStream[String,TestEntity]
```

I tried for hours and still can't believe that this shouldn't work.

I would be very happy if someone could give me a hint how I solve this problem.

I already tried many combinations, I had a workaround with a generic on function level, but this is not compile safe:

```scala
implicit class KGroupedVersionableEntityStreamOps2[K, V <: VersionableEntity[_]]( groupedStream:KGroupedStream[K, V] ) {

  def aggregateByVersionToSet[I]( implicit materialized:Materialized[K, Map[I, V], ByteArrayKeyValueStore] ):KTable[K, Set[V]] =
    groupedStream.aggregate( Map.empty[I, V] )( ( _, value:V, map:Map[I, V] ) =>
      if( map.get( value.id.asInstanceOf[I] ).exists( _.version > value.version ) ) map
      else map + ( value.id.asInstanceOf[I] -> value )
    )
    .mapValues( _.values.toSet )
}
```

```scala
val stream:KGroupedStream[String, TestEntity] = null
val table:KTable[String, Set[TestEntity]] = stream.aggregateByVersionToSet[Long]
```

Demo:
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Vincent-76/JxxlAPKOSn6pyZcX4fNTZA/9

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried getting rid of type parameter of `Entity`? Ie. `trait Entity {
  type I;
  def id:I;
}
`

Comment: If you can create an actual MCVE in **Scastie** that shows the error message, more folks would be able to gave it a look.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks, I did and added the link :)

Comment: This seems to compile: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/KORfFh2rQTyl6s6by9P8Hg - Could you please check on the real code?